# How to implement concurrent.futures with ordered output in Python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am primarily a Go developer and just started writing an app in Python. Here is a similar implementation in Go:

https://github.com/tejzpr/ordered-concurrently

How can I do this in Python?

This is what I have so far:

```
while True:     
    response = iot_sensor.receive()     
    future = executor.submit(response)     # get the future obj from the submission    
    queue.put_nowait(future)               # asyncio.queue(): add the future object to the queue
```

The above code gets the future and adds it to **`asyncio.queue`**. The code below does the queue processing

```
async def run_queue(): 
    print('init queue processor') 
    try: 
        while True: 
            if not queue.empty(): 
                al = queue.get_nowait()      #  get the queue (futures)
                res = al.result()            #  blocking call. i.e., wait for the result from the future before moving on to the next future
                executor.submit(write_to_es, res) 
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)
```

The above waits for **`al.result()`** [**`asyncio.queue()`** and **`al.result()`** executions make the code run concurrently and also process the results in the order they are submitted]  and then submits it again to concurrent futures to write it to elasticsearch).

I was somewhat able to get it to perform how I want.. but, its super slow.. much slower than running the whole thing in the main process.

Comment: Please include a [mre] of the problem you encountered when coding this in Python. How did using concurrent.futures result in the *wrong* output order?

Comment: Please [edit] the question, comments do not preserve the code formatting.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you! I've edited my question and added few details..